# How can i see what is the error in ImageMagick error in php 8.2.5?

Tags: php, imagick

I have installed imagik and GD on my server with PHP Version 8.2.5, php info shows that they are installed, the error that show the site is: [phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi2v5.png) [phpinfo gd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjiVG.png)

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Imagine\Gd\Imagine" not found in

This is what is in that line of code:

```
$imagine =  new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
```

full code:

```php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["slide1"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $file_type = $_FILES["slide1"]["type"];
        $allowed_types = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
            
        if($_FILES["slide1"]["size"] > 15 * MB){
            $size_err = 1;        
        }
        else if (in_array($file_type, $allowed_types)){
            $target_file = "../slides_img/slide1.jpg";
            try {
                $imagine =  new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
                $image = $imagine->open($_FILES["slide1"]["tmp_name"])
                            ->resize(new Imagine\Image\Box(1920, 500))
                            ->save($target_file);
            }
            catch(Imagine\Exception\Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                $up_err = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks for any help!

I installed gd and ImageMagick with the help of our server provider.

** UPDATE **
It seems that problem was solved, now the error is:

> Unable to open image /tmp/phpIG1TK7

on this lines of code:

```php
$target_file = "../slides_img/slide1.jpg";
try {
        $imagine =  new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
    $image = $imagine->open($_FILES["slide1"]["tmp_name"])
                ->resize(new Imagine\Image\Box(1920, 500))
                ->save($target_file);
}
catch(Imagine\Exception\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
```

Comment: You may have installed the extensions, but the classes you're referencing are not part of either of them. You seem to be trying to use the "Imagine" library which doesn't seem to be installed correctly. Try referring to [their docs](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/introduction.html#installation)

Comment: Well, i think i did something right because that error disapear and now it shows:

Unable to open image /tmp/phpIG1TK7

on this lines of code:

                $imagine =  new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
                $image = $imagine->open($_FILES["slide1"]["tmp_name"])
                            ->resize(new Imagine\Image\Box(1920, 500))
                            ->save($target_file);
            }
            catch(Imagine\Exception\Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();